# How to read a text file on my desktop and want to get the data on terminal in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a text file called "mylist.txt". I want to read this file and want to display each and every data which is there in the file on my terminal.  Can you assist me to do this.

Comment: @Maulwurfn Guess I probably shouldn't have answered... my bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('mylist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/home/acer/Desktop/mylist.txt') as f:    #path to the file
    print f.read()
```

learn more about file `read/write` [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Beware this method for really large files (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)